# How to convert a PE to shellcode

Tags: portable-executable, shellcode

I wish to convert the compiled c++ code below to a shellcode

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
   std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

I have a basic idea of the PE format, but don't really know how to go about converting an exe to shellcode, as far as I know I don't need to convert the `MZ` or the dos statement.
What I am asking for is guides or links on this subject or explanation from a more experienced hacker/developer on how would he/she do it not the code it self
what to look for and what frameworks/programming languages to use

I am exploring `pefile` in python but I can't tell if I am on the right track